How can I get the next row value in a column if the return value already exist in the return column?
`How can I get the next row value in a column if the return value already exist in the return column?
I'm trying to make a crew list that will automatically fill out a shift based on their team and operation skills.
So far I've managed to get the correct crew member, but that member can't be covering multiple positions.
=@IFERROR(FILTER('data-sheet'!B3:B36;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(T35;'data-sheet'!K3:K36)+SEARCH(O15;'data-sheet'!M3:M36)));"No match found")
data-sheet'!B3:B36 is Crew list
T35 is Operation skill
'data-sheet'!K3:K36 is List containing operation skill for each crew member
O15 is Team
'data-sheet'!M3:M36 is List containing which team each crew member is on
Now I just need to make sure that a crew member doesn't appear multiple times.
Try to google my way to an answer. But as I'm not skilled enough to understand every function in excel.`
The sheet where I want the output
The sheet containing the data
I hope the file itself will help

Can you add in some sample data and a desired output in text format? Preferably in Table Markdown.

And for single return output, I'd recommend looking into a =VLOOKUP() or an INDEX/MATCH ; but without a data sample it's hard to give you an appropriate example.

Here's one way to do it with =XLOOKUP()
=XLOOKUP(1,($E76=$B$76:$B$81)*(F$75=$C$76:$C$81),$A$76:$A$81)
Where $E76 is the column of skills; $B$76:$B$81 is the list of skills, from each crew member;
F$75 is the team number; $C$76:$C$81 is the list of team numbers, from each crew member;
$A$76:$A$81 is the list of names;
Formula applied in F76:G79 in the example image below.
Make sure to keep the relative positions ($) in place, so you can copy your formula down and to the right.

EDIT:
If I interpretted your positions:
=XLOOKUP(1,($T35='data-sheet'!$K$3:$K$36)*(O$15='data-sheet'!$M$3:$M$36),data-sheet'!$B$3:$B$36)


EDIT2:
So formula applied in D3 of the crew sheet: =XLOOKUP(1,(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C3,'Data-Sheet'!$K$3:$K$36))*($C$11='Data-Sheet'!$M$3:$M$36)*IF(COUNTIFS(D2:$D$2,'Data-Sheet'!$B$3:$B$36)>0,0,1)),'Data-Sheet'!$B$3:$B$36,"No Match")
Pull down and to the right as required, if something weird happens, it's probably because of relative cells, but as far as I tested, it works.
Only note, when you get to a new team, you have to manually adjust the 'team' cell (C$C$11).
Some explanation: C3 is the 'skill', 'Data-Sheet'!$K$3:$K$36 is the list of skills,
$C$11 is the selected team, 'Data-Sheet'!$M$3:$M$36 is the list of teams,
CD2:$D$2is the part that selects all previous workers, and checks if they're already used, 'Data-Sheet'!$B$3:$B$36 is the list of workers.


Edit 3:
Row 1 are just the skill names, row 2 through 13 are autofilled with a formula.
Row 14 shows the Dropdownlist.

In cell Z2 use the following: =FILTER($B$3:$B$36,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Z$1,$K$3:$K$36))*($M$3:$M$36="Team 1"))
In cell AA2 use: =FILTER($B$3:$B$36,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AA$1,$K$3:$K$36))*($M$3:$M$36="Team 1")*(IF(COUNTIFS($Z$14:Z14,$B$3:$B$36)>0,0,1)))
And drag all the way right till cell AG1.
 The data validation is done here once, in row 14, if you want it for every day, there's probably/most likely a better solution, since you'll have to repeat a lot of the above. 
To make the drowdown lists, go to Data -> Data validation -> select list; as source, input Z2 for the first one, AA2 for the second, and so on.

@Lehnskov I think my brain is melting, but check out my new edit, hope it works. You can also delete your previous comments, as they are not necessary anymore.

This is great. It works! Thank you.
Would it work with a dropdown list? Display all that match the criteria and is not already is use in the above cells like it does now?

@Lehnskov I think it might work, best possible approach is using helper columns/tables, but I guess it's possible. I can try something later today if you like.
